# Flash 8 AS2 Mouse click behaviour: clicked spot becomes unclickable until mouse moved

Tags: flash, mouse, actionscript-2, click, double-click

I have a series of buttons on the stage, they can be double clicked using a timer that detects a double click. this all works great until I refresh the page and load another lot of buttons. The the problem starts...

If I click on a spot on the screen I am unable to reclick that same spot. I have to move the mouse slightly to be able to click again. This is causing problems for detecting double click - now its click move click!

Any ideas?

Comment: when you say refresh the page - is that within the flash movie or reload the browser window and the movie reloads?

Comment: Hi, I mean refresh within the flash browser. I present a series of icons on the screen and the user can select by single clicking or open them by double clicking. The icons get refreshed when the user selects some and clicks a button.

Comment: _ sorry im not being clear, refresh within the flash player, no browser refreshing involved. I am refreshing the display with actionscript. It just appears that the mouse has to be moved after the first click before I can make the second click.

Comment: Hi undefined. w/hat I meant in my answer is to write ANOTHER .fla (a simple one) and see if you can get the problem to appear. Either that or debug your code by reading it... either way works, but often in writing the simple .fla you will find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've the very same Problem with CS3 and AS2.0. Has anyone a solution to this problem so far???
I've been trying to solve it for days in a complex Lotery Application.

In this thread http://www.actionscripts.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=141081 I've found the suggestion to lower the frame rate to 12fps but this didn't help either...

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem too in the past and I'm pretty sure I solved it back then. I've been digging through some code but I can't find the code I was looking for but checking out the documentation for the MovieClip object I'm pretty sure it can solved by setting the `focusEnabled` property of your MovieClip to `true` (but I could be wrong :).

I will have another look for the code I was looking for but I need to get in out of backed up storage somewhere...

Comment: Great thank you so much, I'll try that .. this has been annoying me!

Comment: Hi, I tried to add this.enabled = false on my movie clips but didnt work, nor did adding this in this.onRelease(). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but just a methodology, because to answer your question I'd need to fire up a Flash IDE using AS 2.0 (which I try to forget, generally, as I use 3.0 so rarely) and set up a test harness with JUST THE PROBLEM, as you see it. I think once you do that you'd find that either:

1) you've found a real bug in Flash (doubtful), which then will have its answer plastered all over the Internet
2) Most probably: your test harness does NOT exhibit the weird behavior. Then it is a question of figuring out how your real program differs from your test harness.
3) This is really cool: your test harness doesn't work either. Then you put a zip of the .fla in some Web location and we can download it and figure out what's up.

I've looked at some posts about the double click thing in AS2.0 but no one has mentioned this problem.

Comment: Hi Ive added a link to this online if you are able to take a look and let me know what you think. cheers